# Serialize heterogenic array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct, jsonserializer

I have a following JSON string, which I need to serialize and send as a body in POST request.

```
{
    "rules": [[
        {
            "operator": "text_field_contains",
            "args": [
                "8",
                "test"
            ]
        }],
        [{
            "operator": "text_field_contains",
            "args": [
                "6",
                "test"
            ]
        }
    ],
    {
        "operator": "status_any",
        "args": []
    }
    ]
}
```

I'm having problems converting it into a Swift object. As you can see, the `rules` property contains heterogenic array with either `[Rule]` or `Rule` objects, which have following structure:

```
struct Rule: Codable, Equatable {
    let rOperator: String
    let args: [String]?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case rOperator = "operator"
        case args
    }

    init(ruleOperator: String, args: [String]? = nil) {
        self.rOperator = ruleOperator
        self.args = args
    }
}
```

What to do to convert the above JSON into Data?

Comment: If you already have that string at hand, you don't need `codable`. Just convert it to `data` and set your request's body.

Comment: You're right, I've completely missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the below JSON `String`,

```
    let str = """
    {"rules":[[{"operator":"text_field_contains","args":["8","test"]}],[{"operator":"text_field_contains","args":["6","test"]}],{"operator":"status_any","args":[]}]}
    """
```

Simply use `data(using:)` to convert `String` to `Data` like,

```
    if let data = str.data(using: .utf8) {
        //use data here....
    }
```

Comment: There is still a simpler way: `let data = Data(str.utf8)` which returns a non-optional.